# Express JS 4.0, serve binary data, request Accept header changes output

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, base64, utf-16

Thanks in advance.

## Short:

Express JS 4.0 alters the output data, due to the `Accept` headers in the request.
Is there a way for me to override this behaviour, and just write the same data regardless of the request headers.

When `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8` is present output is changed.

Is there a way I can ignore, remove, override these headers.

## Long (probably tl;dr):

I am trying to serve binary data from a Node/ExpressJS app.
I am storing a compressed log file (plain/text), that has been gzipped, base64 encoded and sent to my server app, where it is being stored in a mongo database using mongoose. I know this is probably not optimal, but is currently a necessary evil. This is working fine.

```
$(gzip --stdout /var/log/cloud-init-script.log | base64 --wrap=0)
```

Is being used to compress and base64 the data, before it is sent with other data as part of a json post.

The problem occurs when I attempt to retrieve, decode the base64 encoded string and send to the browser as a binary gzip file.

```
// node, referring to the machine the log came from
var log = new Buffer(node.log, 'base64');

res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + node.name + "-log.gz");
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-gzip');
res.setHeader('Content-Length', log.length);

console.log(log.toString('hex'));
// res.end(log, 'binary'); I tried this hoping I could by pass, some content-negotiation
res.send(log);
```

I had this working when using ExpressJS 3.0 using `res.send`.
But when I updated to ExpressJS 4.0 the downloaded data, ceased to extract properly. The data being pulled down seemingly corrupt somehow.

I started to try and fix this by comparing the downloaded file and the source file in hexidecimal output using `xxd` or `od` and found that the downloaded file was different to the source. I also dumped the hex of the NodeJS Buffer just before it is sent to the client to console, and this matches the source.

I have been banging my head against this issued for nearly a day now, and have suspected that NodeJS might be doing something funky with character encoding (UTF-8 v. Buffer v. UTF16 Strings), OS endianess.

Eventually finding none of this the be problem, I had assumed NodeJS had always been outputting the wrong data to the browser, which was correct, but it wasn't "Always" outputting the wrong data.

I had a break through, when I did a curl request to the endpoint, and the data came through as expected (matching the source), I then added the request headers that were sent with my browser requests, and got back the mangled data.

Actual log file:

```
I'm a log file
```

### Good Request:

```
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Last-Modified: Tue, 26 May 2015 11:47:46 GMT
< Content-Description: File Transfer
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test-log.gz
< Content-Type: application/x-gzip
< Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
< Content-Length: 57
< Date: Tue, 26 May 2015 11:47:46 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive

0000000: 1f8b 0808 0256 6455 0003 636c 6f75 642d  .....VdU..cloud-
0000010: 696e 6974 2d73 6372 6970 742e 6c6f 6700  init-script.log.
0000020: f354 cf55 4854 c8c9 4f57 48cb cc49 e502  .T.UHT..OWH..I..
0000030: 003b 5ff5 5f0f 0000 00                   .;_._....
```

### Bad Request:

```
> Host: localhost:9000
> Connection: keep-alive
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Safari/537.36
> Referer: http://localhost:9000/nodes?query=environment%3D5549b6cbdc023b5e26fe6bd4%20type%3Dnat
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Last-Modified: Tue, 26 May 2015 11:47:00 GMT
< Content-Description: File Transfer
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test-log.gz
< Content-Type: application/x-gzip
< Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
< content-length: 57
< Date: Tue, 26 May 2015 11:47:00 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive

0000000: 1ffd 0808 0256 6455 0003 636c 6f75 642d  .....VdU..cloud-
0000010: 696e 6974 2d73 6372 6970 742e 6c6f 6700  init-script.log.
0000020: fd54 fd55 4854 fdfd 4f57 48fd fd49 fd02  .T.UHT..OWH..I..
0000030: 003b 5ffd 5f0f 0000 00                   .;_._....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res.end(node.log, 'base64');
```

instead of

```
res.send(log);
```

Where node.log is the raw base64 encoded String and log was a Buffer that had decoded that string.

Bearing in mind I am using Node v0.10.38.

I ended up following the function call chain.

```
// I call
res.send(log);
// ExpressJS calls on http.ServerResponse
this.end(chunk, encoding); // chunk = Buffer, encoding = undefined
// NodeJS http.ServerResponse calls
res.inject(string);
```

At this point NodeJS appears to be treating the data as a string, which is where the buffer contents were being mangled.

This behaviour was different when the `'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'` header was not present, a different `end(chunk, encoding)` function was being called in this case,  not using `res.inject` and not mangling the Buffer data.

I am not entirely sure where the content negotiation is happening and what is swapping in the different `res.end` functions, whether this is NodeJS or ExpressJS, but it would be nice to be able to control this content negotiation in some simple way.